# Editing text in a document

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to add XML tags around a text document. Here is my code

```
def codeData(filename):    
    file = open(str(filename), "r")
    info = file.readlines()
    file.close()

#reopen the file
file2 = open(str(filename), "w")
for line in info:
    line = line.replace(line, "<test> " + line + "</test>")
    file2.write(line)
file2.close()
```

Here is my result:
https://gyazo.com/c790b6bc6a1af7f42edc1dfe8d5ca2aa

I want the words to be in the middle of the tags. Could someone give me some assistance?

Comment: post the result here..

Comment: Didn't you get a `NameError` because your `info` variable isn't global variable? Or the `file2 = open(str(filename), "w")...` part should inside the function?

Comment: I didn't get any error from that, no.

Comment: Is it really that hard to copy paste your result?

Comment: Sorry dog, the XML tags were all out of wack and it wasn't working properly. Please forgive me. Won't happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by the `newline` character at the end of each line in your file. A way to remedy this problem is to remove that `newline` at the end of each line.

```
line = line.replace(line, "<test> " + line.rstrip('\n') + "</test>\n")
```

Comment: Hmm, Now the tags are just appearing after the words. It has also put the text into one line.

Comment: @JeremiahSmith See my edit - simply add a `newline` character at the end of the tag.

Comment: Sorry, I did not see the edit. That did the trick. I appreciate the help, Nick

Comment: @JeremiahSmith No problem, glad I could help!